# Configuration to run Nextjs on ie11

Tags: internet-explorer, next.js, internet-explorer-11

I was thinking about making a website for a client using nextjs, but the browser he uses is ie11 (on windows 7), before giving up, i've tried different configurations to get it working.
The Nextjs website says it fully supports IE11, but the pages doesn't show. The error the console is giving is on a template literal.
Is there something i can confiugre to get it working? I haven't loaded any extra libraries.
thanks

Comment: Can you post the actual error you're getting, and any code that may be related to it?

Comment: You said you have tried different configurations, can you please inform us what exactly you had tried? So that we can try to check and make a test with the IE 11 browser. I refer to the steps mentioned in this [document](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app/setup) and I can run the project in the IE 11 browser.

Comment: I was using npx create-next-app. I have tried to download the example and it works, the interface is all messed up, but i guess i can try to change that, Thanks. Do you know what are the differences? later i will post the error

Comment: The error is "not a valid character" -> this the first error in _app.js and index.js by doing "npm create-next-app": const identifier=`${id} ${count}`; maybe there are some others in the file

Comment: Did you make any changes in the code after creating the new project? If yes, I suggest you check whether the code you added is supported in the IE browser. otherwise, you can try to add relevant polyfills for that.